# Can etckeeper be used to track config files outside of /etc?

Tags: git, etckeeper

Specifically I would like to track my `grub.conf` (`/boot/grub/grub.conf`) and some oracle files (i.e. `/db/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`).

I attempted using links; however etckeeper/git only tracks where the link points to, not the actual contents.  And I can not create hard links as the files are on another volume.

I know I could setup another GIT repository but I would rather have it all within etckeeper.

#### Update

Based on nealmcb's answer I came up with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Based on nealmcb's idea/script from http://serverfault.com/questions/211425/

# If you want other configuration data or files on the system also
# opportunistically tracked via etckeeper, use this script to copy them in.

# If there is a hook of some sort available related to the files
# you're mirroring, you can call etckeeper directly and track them
# proactively, rather than just opportunistically here.

MIRROR_ROOT=/etc/etckeeper.mirror.d
echo "etckeeper: mirroring outside files to $MIRROR_ROOT/:"

mirror_dir() {
   LOCAL_PATH=$1
   echo "  $LOCAL_PATH"
   mkdir -p $MIRROR_ROOT/$LOCAL_PATH
   rsync -a $LOCAL_PATH/ $MIRROR_ROOT/$LOCAL_PATH
}


mirror_dir "/boot/grub"
mirror_dir "/root"
```

To add or remove a path you simply add or remove the `mirror_dir` call at the bottom.

Comment: Not a real answer, but since comments aren't allowed (for me at least) above, sharing this:
[How to reuse/extend etckeeper's metadata engine for git control of non-/etc filesystems, or extend git natively with said capability?](http://superuser.com/questions/367729/how-to-reuse-extend-etckeepers-metadata-engine-for-git-control-of-non-etc-file). (Please don't down-tick/ding me for posting a reference here simply because I wasn't able to comment, thx.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I edited the above script to also include plain files.

maybe someone should add a possibility to configure this outside a script (in the etckeeper config?) and send this as a patch to joey hess?

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Based on nealmcb's + ErebusBat's script from http://serverfault.com/questions/211425/

# If you want other configuration data or files on the system also
# opportunistically tracked via etckeeper, use this script to copy them in.

# If there is a hook of some sort available related to the files
# you're mirroring, you can call etckeeper directly and track them
# proactively, rather than just opportunistically here.

MIRROR_ROOT=/etc/etckeeper.mirror.d
echo "etckeeper: mirroring outside files to $MIRROR_ROOT/:"

mirror_dir() {
   LOCAL_PATH=$1
   echo "  $LOCAL_PATH"
   mkdir -p $MIRROR_ROOT/$LOCAL_PATH
   rsync -a --del $LOCAL_PATH/ $MIRROR_ROOT/$LOCAL_PATH
}

mirror_file() {
   LOCAL_PATH=$1
   DIRPATH=`dirname $LOCAL_PATH | head -n 1`
   echo "  $LOCAL_PATH"
   mkdir -p $MIRROR_ROOT/$DIRPATH
   rsync -a --del $LOCAL_PATH $MIRROR_ROOT/$DIRPATH
}
mirror_file "/var/srv/foo_bar/blog/config.py"
mirror_file "/var/srv/foo_bar_another_host/trac/conf/trac.ini"
mirror_file "/tmp/wildcards/*.jpg"
```

Answer (score 4):

etckeeper does allow you to integrate it with other systems.

I also wanted to track changes made by update-grub in /boot, so
I put the code below in `/etc/etckeeper/commit.d/20mirror-outside-files`

This way any time etckeeper is called for other reasons (when I install software, sometimes nightly, etc), it will grab and track revisions in the latest grub configuration.

I invented the convention to put this stuff under /etc/Mirror/*path-to-outside-file*, e.g. `/etc/Mirror/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but if anyone has precedent for another such convention, I'd love to hear about it.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# If you want other configuration data or files on the system also
# opportunistically tracked via etckeeper, use this script to copy them in.

# If there is a hook of some sort available related to the files
# you're mirroring, you can call etckeeper directly and track them
# proactively, rather than just opportunistically here.

echo etckeeper: mirroring outside files

mkdir -p /etc/Mirror/boot/grub
cp -p /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/Mirror/boot/grub
```

**Update:**

Note that for some reason etckeeper doesn't run this when you do an apt-get remove or purge, e.g. to delete an old kernel.  Odd....  But you can run `sudo etckeeper commit` manually in that case, or after a manual `update-grub`.

Answer (score 3):

etckeeper now has a `-d` option to indicate on which directory it must operate.

While hooks to trigger etckeeper generally use construct as `etckeeper pre-install`, ..., you will have to add hooks that use `etckeeper pre-install -d /boot/grub` instead. This shall avoid file duplication in your approach.

Note that if you consider that systemd target, service, ..., files are configuration files (I do - after all, files under `/lib/systemd` are not that different from files under `/etc/init.d`) then this `-d` option will help you to keep track of what happen in `/lib/systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

From synopsis:  `etckeeper init -d /directory`

But beware!  the next time you run it, or next week, if you forget `-d path`, it'll could create a new standalone local repo with the default location in `/etc`.

So I'd recommend committing this important detail to it's config, in etckeeper.conf.   A quick, ``` grep /etc \``which etckeeper\`` ```, reveals:
`ETCKEEPER_DIR=/etc`, and so just use this variable in etckeeper.conf.

```
sed -i '1 i\ETCKEEPER_DIR=/' /etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf
```

From a desire to "keep" other stuff, file attributes included,
`etckeeper init -d /`  worked for me, but later forgetting the detail is annoying. So best to save this detail. Also, `uninit` does not undo using the VCS, it just deletes the whole local repo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think etckeeper will do this, but there are a couple of solutions:

1. reverse the links: put a link out on the filesystem to a file in /etc/
2. script the copying of those files into /etc (backup) and out of /etc (restore).  Then use those scripts periodically or in an appropriate git hook.

Comment: While the reverse link is a good idea, and I use it in some cases there are cases where it won't work.  Specifically don't try the  reverse link for your `grub.conf` or else you won't be able to boot.

Comment: @Zoredache  - Exactly.  However the reverse link would probably work for my Oracle files.  And and @pjz's copy method would probably work for anything on boot (grub + kernel conf).  I will try this next week.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the global setting in etckeeper.conf

```
ETCKEEPER_DIR=/
```

while having a .gitignore that is blacklisting everything but some specific files:

```
*
!.etckeeper
!.gitignore
!etc/
!etc/fstab
# ...
```

etckeeper init worked, etckeeper add as well. However an etckeeper commit still scans all the / tree and doesn't come back. I already removed 20warn-problem-files , because I know the specific files being added. Debugging with bash -x shows

```
+ /etc/etckeeper/commit.d/20store-metadata updates
```